# Add new column in postgres table

Tags: postgresql

My table has two columns type date and I'd like to compare between the two and put the max of them in new column.
in the table, I already added the column max_date to fill it.
I used the command

```
update table
   set max_date AS select MAX(highest) 
                from (values (date1),(date2)) AS value(highest)) from table;
```

I don't know if the command's wrong or I should use another one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a bit of confusion around the usage of the `UPDATE`.

For an update that happens row by row (like yours) the statement should be something along

```
update TABLE_NAME set COLUMN_NAME = WRITE_YOUR_COLUMN_CONDITIONAL_CODE_HERE
```

Taking your example, if you have a table like the following

```
create table my_table (date_1 date, date_2 date, highest date);
insert into my_table (date_1, date_2) values ('2021-02-25','2021-02-24');
insert into my_table (date_1, date_2) values ('2021-02-27','2021-02-28');
insert into my_table (date_1, date_2) values ('2021-02-23','2021-02-23');
```

You should run the following update

```
update my_table set highest = case when date_1 > date_2 then date_1 else date_2 end;
```

Now the `highest` correctly contains the most recent date

```
defaultdb=> select * from my_table;
   date_1   |   date_2   |  highest   
------------+------------+------------
 2021-02-25 | 2021-02-24 | 2021-02-25
 2021-02-27 | 2021-02-28 | 2021-02-28
 2021-02-23 | 2021-02-23 | 2021-02-23
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

The MAX function chooses the maximum value from a column of the result set. To get maximum value for 2 or more columns within a single row use the GREATEST function. So here:

```
update table_name 
   set  highest = greatest(date_1, date_2);
```